# How to call a function using remotecall_fetch ( Julia - parallel)

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I want to run a simple function on process 2. So I defined function like this:

```
julia> f(x,y) = x+y
f (generic function with 1 method)
```

and then I wanted to do it on process 2, but I got an error on it:

```
julia> remotecall_fetch(f,2,1,1)
ERROR: On worker 2:
UndefVarError: #f not defined
deserialize_datatype at ./serialize.jl:969
handle_deserialize at ./serialize.jl:674
deserialize at ./serialize.jl:634
handle_deserialize at ./serialize.jl:681
deserialize_msg at ./distributed/messages.jl:98
message_handler_loop at ./distributed/process_messages.jl:161
process_tcp_streams at ./distributed/process_messages.jl:118
#99 at ./event.jl:73
Stacktrace:
 [1] #remotecall_fetch#141(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Base.Distributed.Worker, ::Int64, ::Vararg{Int64,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:354
 [2] remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Base.Distributed.Worker, ::Int64, ::Vararg{Int64,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:346
 [3] #remotecall_fetch#144(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Vararg{Int64,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:367
 [4] remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Vararg{Int64,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:367
```

I know we can define function like this:

```
julia> @everywhere f(x,y)=x+y
```

and then we can get the result:

```
julia> remotecall_fetch(f,2,3,4)
7
```

Actually I don't know how can I define my functions In all processes or some of them by `Include` or `using`

.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@everywhere` is the correct macro to use. For modules, just do `@everywhere using MyModule` and all the exported functions in module `MyModule` will be available to all worker processes.